# How can I convert this jQuery to React?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I'm relatively new to coding and am working on a React App.  I have some jQuery code that I'd like to use in it but have read it is bad to mix react and jQuery.  I am very unsure of how to turn this into code I can use with react because I'm quite the dolt at this point.  Thanks in advance!

```
var $die = $(".die"),
  sides = 20,
  initialSide = 1,
  lastFace,
  timeoutId,
  transitionDuration = 500,
  animationDuration = 3000;

$("ul > li > a").click(function () {
  reset();
  rollTo($(this).attr("href"));

  return false;
});

function randomFace() {
  var face = Math.floor(Math.random() * sides) + initialSide;
  lastFace = face == lastFace ? randomFace() : face;
  return face;
}

function rollTo(face) {
  clearTimeout(timeoutId);

  $("ul > li > a").removeClass("active");
  $("[href=" + face + "]").addClass("active");

  $die.attr("data-face", face);
}

function reset() {
  $die.attr("data-face", null).removeClass("rolling");
}

$(".randomize, .die").click(function () {
  $die.addClass("rolling");
  clearTimeout(timeoutId);

  timeoutId = setTimeout(function () {
    $die.removeClass("rolling");

    rollTo(randomFace());
  }, animationDuration);

  return false;
});
```

Comment: I think trying to convert code from jQuery to react is the wrong aproach. jQuery is imperative and react is declarativ. Its two completely different ways of writing code and its probably better to go back to what you want your code to do and throw away your jquery code since it wont be something you can reuse.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html in case you haven't read it yet.

Comment: With react, the component can rerender with an "added" class (for what I suppose to be a CSS animation). The `setTimeout` to remove the class will be in the click handler. As Achtung says... Throw jQuery away when using React. It's one or the other.